# Database model upgrade to the industry standard

Tags: java, mysql, spring, database-design

I work on a small bookselling e-commerce website using Java/ Spring boot technology. As I have little experience of database design, I was looking for a model that I can use maybe with little modification, if necessary. I find this database model from a MOOC,

[image]

If the image is not very descriptive, I write only the `TO` relations below with some explanation,

```
A. billing_address table, 
—————————————————————

user_order (1 -> n) // A billing address can potentially receive many user orders 

B. book table,
———————————

cart_item (1 -> n)

book_to_cart_item (1 -> n)


C. book_to_cart_item table, 
———————————————————————


D. cart_item table, 
————————————————

book_to_cart_item (1 -> n) // I dont know the table book_to_cart_item is any necessary 


E. password_reset_token table,
———————————————————————————

User may need to reset the password and we need the token for the very purpose 


F. payment table,
——————————————

[![enter image description here][2]][2]
user_order (1 -> n) // many orders can use the same payment info



G. role table,
———————————

user_role (1 -> n) 


H. shipping_address table,
———————————————————————

user_order (1 -> n) // we can have multiple orders to the same shipping address


I. The shopping_cart table,
————————————————————————

cart_item  (1 -> n) // can have the many cart_item


J. user table,
———————————

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

password_rest_tocken (1 -> n) // may need multiple password reset token

shopping_cart (1 -> n) // every time the customer comes, they will have a new shopping cart 

user_order (1 -> n) // customer can have the nultiple orders 

user_payment (1 -> n) // the user can have multiple credit card in the wallet

user_role (1 -> n) // can have different roles say, the customer or the admin 

user_shopping (1 -> n) // all the shipping info for the particular user



K. user_billing
————————————


L. user_order table,
—————————————————

cart_item (1 -> n) // need one to more items in the per order

billing_address (1 -> n)

shipping_address (1 -> n)

payment (1 -> n) // this captures all the payment info


M. user_payment table,
———————————————————

user_billing (1-> n) // we can use the same payment info for the multiple billing


N. user_role
—————————

O. user_shipping
—————————————
```

Do I need to perform any modifications to the design to upgrade it to the industry standard app? I will be happy to have comments from the experienced database modelers.

Secondly, I have the entity example for the Spring boot app provided below,

```
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    private int roleId;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

    public int getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }

    public void setRoleId(int roleId) {
        this.roleId = roleId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
        return userRoles;
    }

    public void setUserRoles(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to know the entities have any conflicting relations in the Java/ Spring app?  I get to know this before further progressing to write the app

Comment: Most datatypes are unnecessarily bulky.  Can't see what is indexed.  I'm surprised that there are no many-to-many relations.  There are two essentially identical "address" tables; can't they be merged?  Please do not clutter column names with their table names.

Comment: What are the identical address tables?

Comment: Billing_address and shipping_address have very similar schemas (especially after removing the redundant prefix).

Comment: Because they can be different. Btw, do you know how can I check whether there is any conflict among the entities in Java app?